# What statistical learning algorithm library should I use?

Tags: python, machine-learning, statistics

I'm trying to create a statistical learning algorithm that when trained will be able to classify two sets of data based on their differing content, judged by frequency of words used. (I don't know if conditional probability i.e. frequency of one specific word occurring after another word matters that much here). I'm not sure what algorithm would work for me best here (SVM, neural net, etc.), but ideally the library should be in Python, efficient, and easy to use. Input data for the learning algorithm should of course be strings.

Although Python is still preferred, I wouldn't mind using another language as long as it meets all the other criteria I need. I'll consider using basically any language as long as it also has a library for mySQL, and runs on Linux.

**Edit:** After thinking about it for a while, I think the general process I'm going for now is:

1. Tokenize each item in the data set. The data set was an array of strings, now is an array of arrays of strings. (tokens)
2. Keep a lexicon of tokens that are currently in the data set
3. Convert my representations of strings to arrays of integers representing how many times each token in my lexicon occurs in each string.
4. Use the arrays of integers to train the SVM instead of the raw strings themselves.

I don't know if there actually are any libraries out there that deal with raw strings for statistical learning in the way I want to deal with them, so I assume an array of integers wouldn't be an issue.

Note: I would calculate the probabilities from my arrays of integers since the sum of everything in one array would be that array's number of tokens, and then the probabilities are: (number of times token used)/(number of tokens in string)

Comment: The performance of your algorithm would matter a lot on how you pre-process your data, don't underestimate this step! I think SVM is good for something like this, but you can try different algorithm and see what performs better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/) is probably the most popular python machine learning library. It can build [SVMs](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#svm), as well as many other kinds of classifiers, so it should be pretty easy for you to try out a few to see what works best, once you have the data in the right format.

Let's say your lexicon has only 3 words a, b, and c, and you have 2 training data instances "a b" which is class 0 and "c c" which is class 1. Then you can build an SVM as follows:

```
from sklearn import svm
X = [[1, 1, 0], [0, 0, 2]] # training data features
y = [0, 1] # class labels
clf = svm.SVC()
clf.fit(X, y)
```

And predict new values like so:

```
clf.predict([[0, 1, 0]])
```

Comment: Thanks, sklearn has been working great for me so far!